# Java | OO Design | How to map target field from multiple source fields depending on different business conditions?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

**Context:**
I am working on a Java Spring Boot backend service, related to e-commerce domain. My service gets data from Order-Service(OS), and I have to extract some data to send it further. Extracted data class looks something like:

```
class TargetDTO {
    String orderId;
    String shipmentId;
    String trackingUrl;
    String deliveryDate;
    // so on..
}
```

The source data, which I get from OS is contained in a JsonNode , and hence is of free form or no defined schema as below:

```
class OSResponseDTO {
   String field1;
   String field2;
   JsonNode sourceData; // this is of our interest for this problem
   // so on..
}
```

There are 2 dimensions in mapping the data :

1. Mapping criteria from source to target:

   - The data can be directly extracted from source field, e.g. orderId <=> sourceData.orderId
   - The data can be a combination of more than one field, e.g. shipmentId <=> sourceData.orderId + sourceData.shipments.number.
   - We may need to apply some logic, and using one or more source fields, e.g. map deliveryDate from sourceData jsonNode and convert to specific format as per geographical region.
2. Same target data can be mapped from different json paths of sourceData , based upon business conditions, such as orderPlacedOnline, orderPlacedOffline, orderPaidOnline, orderPaidCash, orderPaidCard, orderOutForDelivery, orderDelayed, etc. There are, as of now, about 200 such conditions, which can be grouped in 8-10 schemas.
   For e.g.
   trackingUrl <=>

```
if(orderOutForDelivery) {
  trackingUrl = sourceData.orderDetails.url;
} 
else if(orderPlaced) {
  trackingUrl = sourceData.url;
}
.
.
.
else if(orderShipped) {
  trackingUrl = sourceData.shipments.url;
}
else {
}
```

**Question:** What possible design I can go with to implement this?

**What I have tried**
One approach I could think of was -
Having strategies for mapping each target attribute, and creating a Map of condition and strategies, as:

```
interface OrderIdStrategy {
  void mapOrderId();
}
class OrderIdStrategy1 implements OrderIdStrategy {
}
class OrderIdStrategy2 implements OrderIdStrategy {
}

interface TrackingUrlStrategy {
  void mapTrackingUrl();
}
class TrackingUrlStrategy1 implements TrackingUrlStrategy {
}
class TrackingUrlStrategy2 implements TrackingUrlStrategy {
}

class DataExtractor {
  Map<String, Set<String>> businessCaseAndUsedStrategiesMapping;

  @PostConstruct
  init() {
     businessCaseAndUsedStrategiesMapping.put("orderPlacedOnline", Set.of("OrderIdStrategy1", "TrackingUrlStrategy2"));
     businessCaseAndUsedStrategiesMapping.put("orderOutForDelivery", Set.of("OrderIdStrategy2", "TrackingUrlStrategy2"));
  // so on
  }

  mapOrderId(String businessCase) {
     businessCaseAndUsedStrategiesMapping.get(businessCase).mapOderId();
  }

  mapShipmentId(String businessCase) {
     businessCaseAndUsedStrategiesMapping.get(businessCase).mapShipmentId();
  }

  mapTrackingUrl(String businessCase) {
     businessCaseAndUsedStrategiesMapping.get(businessCase).mapTrackingUrl();
  }
}
```

But the unhappy part of this approach is that I have to create a map for all those 200 business cases; and these business conditions are likely to grow with future.

Comment: You can create different mappers and select one discriminator field, based on this discriminator use that specific mapper to map json to DTO.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing it more object-oriented:

Define the `Order` interface.

```
interface Order {
    String orderId();
    String shipmentId();
    String trackingUrl();
}
```

Define the class `FromOSResponseDtoOrder`:

```
class FromOSResponseDtoOrder implements Order {
    private final OSResponseDtoOrder dto;
    
    public FromOSResponseDTOOrder(OSResponseDtoOrder dto) {
        this.dto = dto;
    }

    public String orderId() {
        // some extracting from dto
    }

    public String shipmentId() {
        // some extracting from dto
    }

    public String trackingUrl() {
        // some extracting from dto
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have different schema of JsonNode in OSResponse, how do I design for that - if(orderShipeed) map from this jsonPath, elseif, elseif, so on.. Obviously we can have multiple if-else, which will always work.

Comment: @user14642363 I would start by analyzing the existing types of orders. If strategies basis on that, I would make a few implementations of the Order interface (FromOSResponseDtoShipedOrder, FromOSResponseDtoNotShipedOrder, etc.), and make choose what object to create on the top level. If you could not classify orders, I would split the Order interface to OrderId, ShipmentId, etc., and make implementations with the constructor that gets OSResponseDtoOrder and set of your strategies (instead if you will use a loop by strategies). In a place where you need to use orderId you will make OrderId.